# Understanding the line #define LPC_CCAN_API ((CCAN_API_T *) (LPC_ROM_API->candApiBase))

Tags: c

I'm programming the NXP controller LPC11C24. In a LPCOpen example I found the following line of code i want to understand.

```
#define LPC_CCAN_API    ((CCAN_API_T *) (LPC_ROM_API->candApiBase))
```

Where CCAN_API_T is a struct.

```
typedef struct CCAN_API {
    void (*init_can)(uint32_t *can_cfg, uint8_t isr_ena);
    void (*isr)(void);
    void (*config_rxmsgobj)(CCAN_MSG_OBJ_T *msg_obj);
    uint8_t (*can_receive)(CCAN_MSG_OBJ_T *msg_obj);
    void (*can_transmit)(CCAN_MSG_OBJ_T *msg_obj);
    void (*config_canopen)(CCAN_CANOPENCFG_T *canopen_cfg);
    void (*canopen_handler)(void);
    void (*config_calb)(CCAN_CALLBACKS_T *callback_cfg);
} CCAN_API_T;
```

And where LPC_ROM_API and candApiBase are defined as

```
#define LPC_ROM_API     (*((LPC_ROM_API_T        * *) LPC_ROM_API_BASE_LOC))

#define LPC_ROM_API_BASE_LOC      0x1FFF1FF8 

typedef struct {
    const uint32_t usbdApiBase;             /*!< USBD API function table base address */
    const uint32_t reserved0;               /*!< Reserved */
    const uint32_t candApiBase;             /*!< CAN API function table base address */
    const uint32_t pwrApiBase;              /*!< Power API function table base address */
    const uint32_t reserved1;               /*!< Reserved */
    const uint32_t reserved2;               /*!< Reserved */
    const uint32_t reserved3;               /*!< Reserved */
    const uint32_t reserved4;               /*!< Reserved */
} LPC_ROM_API_T;
```

I understand that LPC_ROM_API_BASE_LOC is a a fixed location in ROM that contains a pointer to the ROM driver table. This ROM driver table is LPC_ROM_API_T.

So is LPC_ROM_API a pointer to a pointer of type LPC_ROM_API_T where at the address that this pointer points on is LPC_ROM_API_BASE_LOC written?

Comment: I'm struggling to parse your last sentence, but I think it's correct, yes: LPC_ROM_API is a pointer read from LPC_ROM_API_BASE_LOC to a LPC_ROM_API_T structure.

Comment: So what is ((CCAN_API_T *) (LPC_ROM_API->candApiBase)) exactly? LPC_ROM_API      is placed as this and for my understanding this expression is like CCAN_API_T * dummy = LPC_ROM_API->candApiBase;

Answer (score 0):

To run through the various macros:

- as you said, LPC_ROM_API_BASE_LOC is a a fixed location in ROM that points to a LPC_ROM_API_T structure.
- LPC_ROM_API is the pointer to LPC_ROM_API_T read from LPC_ROM_API_BASE_LOC, cast to be a LPC_ROM_API_T pointer.
- LPC_ROM_API->candApiBase is the pointer to the CCAN_API_T structure. It's stored as a const uint32_t, not a pointer, so needs to be cast to a CCAN_API_T pointer for use.
- LPC_CCAN_API is a pointer to the CCAN_API_T structure read from LPC_ROM_API->candApiBase and correctly cast to be a CCAN_API_T pointer.

You can call methods on LPC_CCAN_API directly:

```
uint32_t can_cfg = 456;
LPC_CCAN_API->init_can(&can_cfg, 123);
```

(I don't know the API so I've no idea what these values should be.)

Comment: From the user manual: "The on-chip drivers are stored in boot ROM and offer CAN and CANopen initialization and communication features to user applications via a defined API. The following functions are included in the API". For me it looks like I have to call the API this way to make sure I can call the defined functions stored in the ROM. As you said, in the program I call the API like this: LPC_CCAN_API->isr();